# Stacklayout Inside Stackedlayout Binding IsVisible

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml view that is a simple listview which has a couple of stackedlayouts in the cells along with some simple binding of my model:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:directory="clr-namespace:Directory;assembly=Directory"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Directory.Models"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Directory.ViewModels;assembly=Directory"
             x:Class="Directory.Views.DirectoryList">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:MasterViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView Margin="0,10"  
              ItemTapped="ListViewItem_Tabbed"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleCollectionGrouped}"  
              IsGroupingEnabled="True"
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
              GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
              HasUnevenRows="True" 
              BackgroundColor="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:People">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid
                        Padding="10"
                        ColumnSpacing="10"
                        RowSpacing="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <controls:CircleImage
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderThickness="3"
                            HeightRequest="66"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            WidthRequest="66" />
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Location}" />
                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"  
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                         Margin="0,0,80,0">
                                <Button Text="Place Order"  
                                        WidthRequest="110"  
                                        FontSize="15"  
                                        BackgroundColor="Chocolate"  
                                        TextColor="White"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

All the bindings work apart from the IsVisible binding which causes the app to crash with:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code
```

If I change my Xaml so that the IsVisible property is not binded and just set to "True" then it compiles and loads.

I have no idea why this isn't working as the other values from the model are binded correctly.

Here is the People model, which "PeopleCollectionGrouped" is of:

```
public class People
{
    [JsonProperty("photo_url")]
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("middle_name")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    public string NameSort
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FullName) || FullName.Length == 0)
            {
                return "?";
            }

            return FullName[0].ToString().ToUpper();
        }
    }


    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone can spot where i have gone wrong it would help

Comment: I really think this is a deeper issue, the code you provided should work. Invalid IL code is not something that is caused by misbinding. Are you sure that when you debug, IsVisible is populated correctly for each People instance inside your `PeopleCollectionGrouped` collection?

Comment: @iSpain17 IsVisible is populated in the PeopleCollectionGroup collection. If I change the layout to something simpler like this: https://gist.github.com/jaymarvels/2cb1ed0c790859d679e557a0ae09e76f  then it binds correctly

Comment: @jaymarvels, i reduced your sample a bit to implement mocked data on my side, and it is working right (when set to false the IsVisible proplerty of a People object the button does not display, as expected). 

Could you please reduce your problem and produce an as-simple-as-posible sample where the problem is still showing? (maybe on the way yourself realize what the actual problem is :P)

Comment: But what do you see when you debug for the IsVisible property after it's set?

Comment: @jaymarvels Hi , you should bind a `ViewModel` for `Xaml` .From shared code , not finding code about `ItemSource` of `ListView`.